# Завершение работы QRunnable

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Использую `QThreadPool` и `QRunnable`. Как завершить работу `QRunnable`, если тот из очереди уже перешёл в состояние выполнения?

В `QThreadPool` имеется метод, позволяющий изымать из пула объекты выполнения, но только тех из них, что всё ещё находятся в очереди.

По идее, в наследнике `QRunnable` нужен некий флаг (наподобие `QThread::requestInterruption()`), который можно было бы переключать из вне, а уже объект выполнения смотрел бы время от времени значение этого флага. Соответственно, если настала пора закругляться, то и завершал бы свою работу.

Однако в этом случае нужно хранить список объектов `QRunnable`, чтобы иметь возможность установки флага, и в итоге иметь вероятность краха программы, если `QThreadPool` кого-либо из них заблаговременно уничтожит. Отказываться от `QRunnable::autoDelete() == true` совсем не хочется.

Есть ли возможность как-то решить эту проблему, не уходя в сторону `QThread` и не изменяя `QRunnable::autoDelete() == true`, так как уж очень подкупает удобство использования `QThreadPool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вас не устраивает функция отмены в наследнике `QRunnable`, тогда можно сделать по другому. Пусть наследник имеет конструктор, который принимает указатель на `QAtomicInteger`. Ещё будет конструктор, которые не будет принимать этот указатель — по умолчанию, в классе, он будет равен `nullptr`.

Внутри метода `run` если указатель не нулевой, и его значение по указателю(полученное через `load()`) равно, скажем, `1`, тогда задание было отменено и мы немедленно завершаем выполнение.

Как Вы уже поняли, этот указатель будет предоставляться тем кодом, что создаёт `QRunnable` и его значение будет выставляться там же.

---

Код может выглядеть так:

```
class MyRunnable: public QRunnable
{
public:
    MyRunnable(QAtomicInteger* cancelationToken): 
        m_CancelationToken{cancelationToken}
    {

    }
    void run() override
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(m_CancelationToken && m_CancelationToken->load() == 1)
                return;
        }
    }
private:
    QAtomicInteger* m_CancelationToken = nullptr;
};
```

Где-то в коде:

```
QAtomicInteger cancel;
auto runnable = new MyRunnable(&cancel);
...
cancel = 1;
```

Comment: простите, не могу сообразить, как работает то, что Вы описали. Не могли бы Вы привести минимальный пример кода этой конструкции?

Comment: А-а-а, всё, я Вас понял. То есть нужно будет во вне хранить список атомарных указателей. Хорошее решение, мне нравится, спасибо.

Comment: @alexis031182, привёл пример. Можно хранить список, а можно одним все сразу отменять — выбор за Вами.

Comment: Спасибо большое, великолепное решение.